# Invalid Login Attempt with correct credentials ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

So i have setted up my ASP.NET Identity login to use the Username instead of the email. On Startup a poweruser gets created with a username and password i know, but when i try to login, it says the login attempt was invalid. I dont know why it does this, since most fixes on Stackoverflow were for those cases, where you use the email. Thank you in advance.

The form in Login.cshtml:

```html
<form id="account" method="post">
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.UserName"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                            <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The Login.cshtml.cs file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace BPW.Cloud.Backend.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect("./dashboard");
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

And the point where i create the poweruser on startup:

```cs
private static async Task CreatePowerUser(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            string userName = configuration.GetSection("PowerUser").GetValue<string>("Username");
            string password = configuration.GetSection("PowerUser").GetValue<string>("Password");

            var powerUser = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = userName
            };

            var createPowerUser = await userManager.CreateAsync(powerUser, password);
            if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(powerUser, "Admin");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `EmailConfirmed` to `true` when creating user :

```
var powerUser = new IdentityUser
{
    UserName = userName,
    EmailConfirmed = true
};
```

Since by default asp.net core identity requires email confirmed with option :

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

If not confirmed , user is not allowed to sign in .